# Plugin com.intershop.gradle.jaxb was not found

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to use jaxb-gradle-plugin and getting plugin not fond error. How to fix that?

```
plugins {
    id 'com.intershop.gradle.jaxb' version '5.1.0'
}

jaxb {
     // generate java code from schema
     javaGen {
        //generates a 'project' schema file from existing java code
        name {
            schema = file('schema.xsd')
            binding = file('binding.xjb')
        }
    }
}
```

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.intershop.gradle.jaxb', version: '5.1.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.intershop.gradle.jaxb:com.intershop.gradle.jaxb.gradle.plugin:5.1.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Stacktrace:

```
 Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.intershop.gradle.jaxb:com.intershop.gradle.jaxb.gradle.plugin:5.1.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:268)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.access$100(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:63)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$1.transform(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:93)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$1.transform(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:89)
        at org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:207)
        at org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:201)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:89)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
```

Comment: This is weird, because this plugin in found in the Plugin Repositories. On my side it's working correctly. Do you have offline mode enabled?

Comment: No. Gradle is behind corporate Artifactory, I am wondering if this can be an issue. All other plugins download well.

Comment: Try running the build with `--stacktrace`, and post the detailed error.

Comment: Thank for looking, added a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to find the jaxb plugin from Gradle Plugin Repository. So let's add a mirror, which is no other than `mavenCentral()`. Assuming that you're using a Gradle version > 7.0. Add `mavenCentral()` to your `settings.gradle` file:

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    ...
  }
}
```

If it gives an error, try the legacy `buildscript {}` method.